# Stopping more than one instance of a function running at a time

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am fairly new to JavaScript and have searched everywhere for an answer to my question and cant seem to find anything related at all. This tells me that I'm missing something with my understanding of how my program works.

I have written a small game where the player navigates through a randomly generated maze using a gameloop that checks keydown events every x milliseconds. The game has a difficulty dropdown menu and then the game is started my clicking a button that calls a function to create a canvas where the game is drawn.

My problem is that when the button is clicked again to create a new maze without reloading the page, the gameloop for the original maze is still running and so key events are registered twice. This is causing some unexpected behavior. It's as though every time the button is clicked, a new instance of the function is running. Is there some way that each time the button is clicked I can set it to stop the previous game function?

```
var canvas;
var div;
var mazeGenButton;

$(document).ready(function () {
    canvas = null;
    div = document.getElementById('canvascontainer');;

    mazeGenButton = document.getElementById("mazeGenButton");
    mazeGenButton.onclick = createInstance;
});

function createInstance() {
    if (canvas != null) {
        div.removeChild(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));
    }
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "myCanvas";
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 1000;
    div.appendChild(canvas);
    drawMaze();
};

var drawMaze = function () {

//code here to create the game(not posted)

//here is the Key listener - not sure if it's related
var keyState = {};
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = true;
    }, true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = false;
    }, true);

    function gameLoop() {
        //left
        if (keyState[37] || keyState[65]) {
            if (isLegalMove(playerXPos - 1, playerYPos)) {
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].removePlayerCell();
                playerXPos -= 1;
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].setPlayerCell();
            }
        }
        //right
        if (keyState[39] || keyState[68]) {
            if (isLegalMove(playerXPos + 1, playerYPos)) {
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].removePlayerCell();
                playerXPos += 1;
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].setPlayerCell();
            }
        }
        //up
        if (keyState[38] || keyState[87]) {
            if (isLegalMove(playerXPos, playerYPos - 1)) {
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].removePlayerCell();
                playerYPos -= 1;
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].setPlayerCell();
            }
        }
        //down
        if (keyState[40] || keyState[83]) {
            if (isLegalMove(playerXPos, playerYPos + 1)) {
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].removePlayerCell();
                playerYPos += 1;
                grid[playerXPos][playerYPos].setPlayerCell();
            }
        }

        drawSurroundingCells();

        setTimeout(gameLoop, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your event binding code in the answer.

Comment: No, do not put code that belongs in the question in an answer. You can always edit your question to include additional information.

Comment: ^ By clicking the [edit] link in your question. You can either a) make your code work so that event handlers have only be bound once when the page loads b) unbind any existing event handlers when a new game is started c) destroy all the elements to which event handlers are bound. I recommend (a).

Comment: You can call `removeEventListener()` to remove the event binding (if you created it with `addEventListener()`). Or you can check a global variable, and return from the function if it's set.

Comment: So add a Boolean and check if the game is running before running it again. If it is running exit.

Comment: @FelixKling Could you please take a look at the edited question. As you can see the Event Listener is bound once the drawMaze() function is called so I assumed that calling it for a second time would simply override the original listener. Am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: @Barmar Adding `removeEventLister()` to the function doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: @dmt You can't use anonymous functions if you want to remove them with `removeEventListener()`. You need to use a named function so you can remove the same function you added.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I have changed the anonymous functions to named ones. Still has no effect. Where should I be removing the event listener? on the button click event?

Comment: Yes. If you do `startButton.addEventListener('click', startApplication)`, then `startApplication` should contain `startButton.removeEventListener('click', startApplication)`

Comment: @Barmar I don't actually want to remove the button functionality. The problem is that when the button is clicked multiple times there seem to be more than once instance of the game running even though you cant see the other one.

Comment: Then just have the function check whether the game is already running, and return immediately if it is.

Comment: `if (game_running) { return; } else { game_running = true; }`

Comment: @Barmar ok I can do that but what about if I want to stop the current game from running and replace it with the new one when the button is clicked?

Comment: Then do that. Just put whatever you need to do in the `if` statement.

Comment: @Barmar sorry to bother you but I'm not still sure how to stop the function from running in the if statement. Is there any reference material you can direct me to?

Comment: There shouldn't be a function running. Javascript applications are event-driven, you don't stay in a function. So there are just a bunch of variables and DOM elements that contain the current state of the application, and your event handlers make use of them. All you need to do is set everything back to its initial state.